# Git bash change of directory

Tags: git, git-bash

How do i change from a sub-directory to a directory in git bash. i know how to navigate into a directory with this code.

```
cd desktop/projects/react-redux.
```

however, navigating to a directory from a sub-directory is what is giving me problems. from the the path above, i want to cd in *projects* directory from the *react-redux* . this how i did it and it did not work.

```
cd ..
```

i have spent too much time on this thing. please guys help me out

Comment: What directory does bash say you're in?

Comment: Hi. I can't see why it wouldn't work. What was the result of cd ..

Comment: i have my answer.. thank you alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there were **no spaces** in the command:

```
cd..

# should be written:
cd ..
```

---

Comment: thank you alot. but what i wanted is to move from the reac-redux directory to the projects directory.

Comment: what is your `pwd` output?

Comment: does my current directory..  /c/users/pm/desktop/projects/react-redux

Comment: and when you type `cd ..` it does not take you one folder back to your project folder?

Comment: cd.. yes it does not take me a folder back

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: looks like you wa not on the right directory. This is what `pwd` is for

Comment: ooo it worked now..  this worked  cd .. instead of cd.. //no space between cd and the dots ..

Comment: Glad to help you out.